# Two different classes with identical AssemblyQualifiedName?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, mstest, type-mismatch

In a MSTest project I declare an internal class for a few tests. It's declared in the test project's namespace like this:

```
namespace Körningar.Test.Hjälpklasser
{
    internal interface ITestkörningParams { int Heltal { get; } string Text { get; } }
    internal class TestkörningParams : ITestkörningParams { public int Heltal { get; set; } public string Text { get; set; } }
    // ...
}
```

In a tested method I have an instance of this class `parms`, and iterate through it's properties to log its values:

```
// Create parms of type körningsparametrarKlass.
object parms = paramhämtare.HämtaParametrar(args, körningsparametrarKlass);

// Log the property values of the parms object.
log.Info($"Körningsparametrar:\r\n"
    + string.Join("\r\n",
        körningsparametrarKlass.GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.GetGetMethod() != null)
        .Select(pi
          => $"{pi.Name} = {Convert.ToString(pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(parms, null))}")
    )
);
```

This line of code throws a `TargetException` with message saying that the object doesn't match the target type.

The method `paramhämtare.HämtaParametrar` creates is from an NSubstitute mock object that does:

```
paramhämtareMock.HämtaParametrar(new string[] { }, null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(new TestkörningParams());
```

I fail to see how the parms object could possibly be the wrong type for a property getter that's extracted from `körningsparametrarKlass`, which is the same type that's instantiated for the `parms` object.

Examining the variables in VS Watch windows gives the following:

[image: Dump from VS 2017 Watch window]

As you can see, the AssemblyQualifiedName is the same for the `parms` object and the `körningsparametrarKlass` type, but the actual type objects differ (marked in the dump). As far as I know type objects should be comparable using `==`, but I have also tested with `körningsparametrarKlass.Equals(parms.GetType())` with the same result. Also note that all lines in the Watch window are actually up to date even though some are gray - I refreshed them all before taking the dump.

How can this happen, and how would i fix it?

I should also mention that this seems to happen only if I run tests for both this test project and another test project in the same solution. If I run only the test in question, or the entire test project that contains it, there is no exception.

**[EDIT]**
It has occurred to me that the problems probably occur when a Type object is derived from an `AssemblyQualifiedName` inside the tested assembly. This type object is apparently different from `typeof(TheClass)` called inside the test assembly. And this problem occurs only if I'm running tests for both this test assembly and another one. There shouldn't be any name or even namespace clashes between these assemblies, regarding the types in question.

Comment: Note: the class `TestkörningParams` is declared in the test assembly, but the instantiating code is executed in the tested assembly. The mock is of course also implemented in the test assembly, where it simply calls the class' constructor to return an object. Just in case it matters...

Comment: If the log line is changed to use `parms.GetType()` instead of `körningsparametrarKlass`, it works fine.

Comment: Also, changing the mock as follows works: `paramhämtareMock.HämtaParametrar(new string[] { }, Arg.Any<Type>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(callinfo => Activator.CreateInstance(callinfo.ArgAt<Type>(1)));`. But that causes a subsequent assert in the test method to fail: `Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Testkörning), körningsklass)`. So apparently, there's still some kind of type mixup. In this case, it's a mismatch of another class from the test assembly and a the type object that's supposed to refer to that class, derived from its AssemblyQualifiedName, similar to the param classes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the cause of the problem.

I have two test assemblies, let's call them `Test1` and `Test2`, which contain tests for assemblies `Ass1` and `Ass2` respectively.

`Test1` has a reference to `Test2`. `Test2` contains an internal class named `TheClass`.

In `Ass2`, some code uses an assembly qualified name to obtain a `Type` object representing `TheClass`.

The problem is that at this time, there are two "versions" of `TheClass`: The one in `Test2` and the one that gets included in `Test1` because of that assembly's reference to `Test2`.

So, apparently the `Type` object represents the one from `Test1`, while the references to `TheClass` inside `Test2` obviously represents the one from `Test2`.

What surprises me is that the test framework will actually load the `Test1` assembly when running the `Test2` tests. Is this supposed to happen, and can it be avoided?